# Remove File with white spaces on its name

Tags: c, file

I have a file named "my file.pdf" and I can't delete this file with this code:

```
if (remove("/var/tmp/\"my file.pdf\"") != 0)
            printf( "Error deleting file\n");
```

Any suggestion different than do some regex to replace '{whitespace}' for '\{whitespace}'?

Comment: You sure that its a problem due to whitespace?

Comment: Note that your error printf does not include a terminating carriage return (\n) and it's customary to put error output to standard error, i.e. fprintf(stderr, "Error deleting file\n");

Comment: @jmtd I know that, this was just an quick example. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remove() function does not use regexes. Does your file really contain quote characters as well as spaces? If not, and if the file contains a single space then:

```
if (remove("/var/tmp/my file.pdf") != 0)
```

should work.

Comment: That was my first attempt and it was not working. But I tried again and it's working now. Ty

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (remove("\"/var/tmp/my file.pdf\"") != 0)
    printf( "Error deleting file");
```

?